# getting null value in database when posting using axios

Tags: database, axios, posting

i was working on a simple spring boot project. the backend is working and its posting and getting data. when i post from swwager i get the data in the frontend table, but when i send the user data from the registeration form it is not displaying on the frontend.

this is the code
Adduser.js

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export default function AddUser() {
  let navigate = useNavigate();

  const [user, setUser] = useState({
    name: "",
    username: "",
    email: "",
  });

  const { name, username, email } = user;

  const onInputChange = (e) => {
    setUser({ ...user, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  const onSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await axios.post("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/AddUser", user);
    navigate("/");
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-6 offset-md-3 border rounded p-4 mt-2 shadow">
          <h2 className="text-center m-4">Register User</h2>

          <form onSubmit={(e) => onSubmit(e)}>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <label htmlFor="Name" className="form-label">
                Name
              </label>
              <input
                type={"text"}
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Enter your name"
                name="name"
                value={name}
                onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e)}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <label htmlFor="Username" className="form-label">
                Username
              </label>
              <input
                type={"text"}
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Enter your username"
                name="username"
                value={username}
                onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e)}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <label htmlFor="Email" className="form-label">
                E-mail
              </label>
              <input
                type={"text"}
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Enter your e-mail address"
                name="email"
                value={email}
                onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e)}
              />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-outline-primary">
              Submit
            </button>
            <Link className="btn btn-outline-danger mx-2" to="/">
              Cancel
            </Link>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Home.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
export default function  Home() {

        const [users,setUsers] = useState([]);


        useEffect(()=> {
            loadUsers();
        },[]);

        const loadUsers=async()=>{
            const result=await axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/AllUser")
            setUsers(result.data);

        }
  return (
    <div className='container'>
        <div className='py-4'>
        <table className="table border table-striped shadow ">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">name</th>
      <th scope="col">Username</th>
      <th scope="col">Email</th>
      <th scope='col'>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {
        users.map((user,index)=>(
            <tr>
      <th scope="row" key={index}>{index}</th>
      <td>{user.name}</td>
      <td>{user.username}</td>
      <td>{user.email}</td>
      <td>
        <button className='btn btn-primary mx-2'>View</button>
        <button className='btn btn-outline-primary mx-2'>Edit</button>
        <button className='btn btn-danger mx-2'>Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
        ))
    }

  </tbody>
</table>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
import Navbar from './layout/Navbar';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import AddUser from './users/AddUser';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path='/' element={<Home />} />
          <Route exact path='/api/v1/Adduser' element={<AddUser />} />
        </Routes>
  
      </Router>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

//http://localhost:8080/api/v1/AddUser
```

need help where did i go wrong.

i tried this

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function AddUser() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [user, setUsers] = useState({
    name: '',
    username: '',
    email: '',
  });

  const { name, username, email } = user;

  const onInputChange = (e) => {
    setUsers({ ...user, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  const onSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {

      const responsePost = await axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/AddUser', user);
      if (responsePost.status == 201) {
        const responseGet = await axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/AllUser');
        if (responseGet.status == 200){
          navigate('/')
        }
        setUsers(responseGet.data)
      }
      
      console.log('User added successfully:', responsePost.data);
      navigate('/');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    }
  };

  // Fetch data when the component mounts
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/AllUser');
        console.log('Data fetched successfully:', response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();


  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-6 offset-md-3 border rounded p-4 mt-2 shadow">
          <h2 className="text-center m-4">Register User</h2>

          <form onSubmit={(e) => onSubmit(e)}>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <label htmlFor="name" className="form-label">
                Name
              </label>
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Enter your name"
                name="name"
                value={name}
                onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e)}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <label htmlFor="username" className="form-label">
                Username
              </label>
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Enter your username"
                name="username"
                value={username}
                onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e)}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <label htmlFor="email" className="form-label">
                E-mail
              </label>
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Enter your e-mail address"
                name="email"
                value={email}
                onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e)}
              />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-outline-primary">
              Submit
            </button>
            <Link className="btn btn-outline-danger mx-2" to="/">
              Cancel
            </Link>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```